# C# - is this possible to declare a class where all fields are wrappers of another class's fields?

Tags: c#, .net, class, oop

Please feel free to modify the title, I couldn't come up with any better one =\

Given the following example class

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name;
    public int ID;
    public string City;
}
```

I need to create another mirror class, where every field is actually a wrapper of the original class:

```
public class PersonMirror
{
    public FieldWrapper<string> Name;
    public FieldWrapper<int> ID;
    public FieldWrapper<string> City;
}
public class FieldWrapper<T>
{
    public T Value;
    public bool someBool;
    public int someCounter;
    // ..whatever
}
```

The thing is, I have many classes to mirror, and some of them have many fields! Moreover, the original class may be changed from time to time (add / remove / rename field), and every change must be applied to the mirrored class - not a good practice for maintainability.

My question is - is there a **type safe** way automate the **decleration** (rather then **creation**, such as generated code) of such mirrored classes?

EDIT:
Let's start from the beginning. In our SOA system, there is a resource access service (serviceX) responsible for updating items in the DB. Other services send it the **modifications** they would like to perform - in json that would be something like: `{ID: 123, name : "myNewName"}`. serviceX would then build an update query to send to the DB. However, there is a requirement that serviceX will expose a POCO interface, so that the interface will be language independent, so expressions such as `(p=> p.name, "MyNewName")` are not allowed. Another requirement is type safety, so json is not allowed either. Currently, the above solution is the best one we came up to answer all the requirements. Any better solutions are more then welcome!

Comment: Are you looking something like this http://www.castleproject.org/projects/dynamicproxy/

Comment: @Eser No, I don't think so. It doesn't seem to satisfy type safety in compile-time.. But thanks!

Comment: What's the problem you are trying to solve here? Perhaps we can offer a better solution?

Comment: @MDeSchaepmeester thanks of the offer, but unfortunately I'm forced to use this 'solution'.

Comment: @shay__ Frankly... find another job :P

Comment: @MDeSchaepmeester see my edit please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO, there's no way to do what you want, except code generation.
Approaches for code generation could differ (this maybe source code generation + compilation, emitting IL code, either your own or existing one), but this is the only way.

Answer (score 1):

use T4 to autogenerate your "WrapperClass".

Below, a proposition of how you could implement your FieldWrapper.

```
public class FieldWrapper<T, O>
{
    private T _item;
    private O _owner;
    private PropertyInfo _setter;

    public T Value
    {
         get { return _item; }
         set {
           if (!EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equal(_item, value))
           {
                _item = value;
                // do some personal check
                _setter.SetValue(_owner, value);
           }
         }
    }

    public bool someBool;
    public int someCounter;
    // ..whatever

    // CTOR
    public FieldWrapper(O owner, Expression<Func<T, O>> propertyExpressionInTheOwner)
    {
       _owner = owner;
       propertyName = (propertyExpressionInTheOwner.body as MemberExpression).Member.Name;
       // get PropertyInfo using the owner and propertyName
    }
}
```

Using the expression behavior permits you to create your fieldWrapper this way.

```
var p = new Person();
new FieldWrapper(p, (pers) => pers.Name);
```

The good point with this technique it is that if you person class change you will directly receive a compilation error.

With T4 the must is to load the assembly where all you class are, tag you class model with a specific attribute. Look into the assembly to found every class that have this attribute and generate the wrapper class associate.

Comment: This is very interesting, I will check that out!

Answer (score 0):

You would have to run it after every code change, but you could create a code parsing application.

List desired keywords to substitute, such as " string ", " int ". Read the file, line by line. Find definition of classes (line contains "class"), then replace every instance of any given keyword in it with:

```
"FieldWrapper<" + keyword + ">"
```

You might want to drop keyword substitution inside methods (and perhaps in the method signatures / return types themselves) of  by checking for "(" and ")", and the opening curly brace. Resume operation when you reach the closing curly brace. You can achieve that by storing the nesting level in an integer, incrementing it when hitting '{' and decrementing it when reaching '}'.

Comment: Thanks, but that an automation of the creation of the class, I'm looking for a (non-existing, probably) way to automate the declaration of it.